# How to use HorizontalGridView

Tags: android, gridview, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to use `HorizontalGridView`. But, it's not easy to make it scroll horizontally. I don't know how to use `HorizontalGridView` exactly. So, used it like `RecyclerView` as follows.

```
private class GridViewAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridViewAdaptor.ViewHolder> {
        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<String> mPathList;

        GridViewAdaptor(Context context, ArrayList<String> pathList) {
            mContext = context;
            mPathList = pathList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mPathList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_top_menu_sub, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            GlideApp.with(mContext).load(R.raw.image_1).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE).apply(new RequestOptions().fitCenter()).into(holder.mImage);
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView mImage;

            ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_top_menu_sub);
            }
        }
}
```

And... this code is at `onCreate()`. To simplify the test, I added dummies to `pathList` and used only one image to load.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mTopMenuSubGrid = new HorizontalGridView(this);
    mTopMenuSubGrid.setLayoutParams(params);
    mTopMenuSubGrid.setNumRows(1);
    mTopMenuSubGrid.setHorizontalSpacing(space);
    mTopMenuSubGrid.setVerticalSpacing(space);

    ArrayList<String> pathList = new ArrayList<>();
    pathList.add("0");
    pathList.add("1");
    pathList.add("2");
    pathList.add("3");
    pathList.add("4");
    pathList.add("5");
    pathList.add("6");
    pathList.add("7");

    GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
    mTopMenuSubGrid.setLayoutManager(manager);
    mTopMenuSubGrid.setAdapter(new GridViewAdaptor(this, pathList));
    mTopMenuSubLayout.addView(mTopMenuSubGrid);
```

This code shows 8 same images on `HorizontalGridView`. However, that grid view scrolls vertically. I want to scroll horizontally. Please let me know what wrong is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this constructor

```
new GridLayoutManager(this, 1, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

You can set the number of spanCount as per your requirement.

Comment: I'm trying to use this too but app keeps crashing, can't find any docs. how did you declare the HorizontalGridView in XML ? Also did you need a gradle implementation entry ?

Comment: its cool i found it (androidx): implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'